# PHP OOP, как обновить данные в БД с помощью массива?

Tags: php, ооп

Это моя функция:

```
public function update($params){
    try{
        $params = array();
        $post_id = $_GET['id'];
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE $this->tabname SET title= ?, post= ?, updated= ? WHERE id=$post_id ");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $params[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $params[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $params[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

А это мой файл `editor.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      $title = $_POST["title"];
      $post = $_POST["post"];
      $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $params = array("$title","$post","$date");
      $update = new DatabaseEdit('posts');
      $update->update($params);
      header("location: posts.php");
  }
?>
```

Когда нажимаю `submit`, обновляет на пустые строки. В чем проблема?

Comment: Выложите код формы. Подозреваю, что у вас `$_POST["submit"]` отсутствует. `WHERE id=$post_id "` PDO служит, чтобы так не делать от слова никогда

Answer (score 3):

Дружище, у тебя массив параметров обнуляется сразу после `try`, вот и вся загвоздка. тест на внимательность :)
и еще, есть отличие `bindParam()` от `bindValue()`: `bindParam()` передает параметр по ссылке, в то время как `bindValue()` - нет